# Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso, circleci

When trying to build android app Espresso Instrumentation Tests with circleci `Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite.`

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

Test results saved as file:/home/circleci/code/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/test-result.pb. Inspect these results in Android Studio by selecting Run > Import Tests From File from the menu bar and importing test-result.pb.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/circleci/code/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
74 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 73 up-to-date

<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLEMax tries reached (2)

Exited with code exit status 1

Answer (score 8):

Saw a similar error when running a test on an emulator unrelated to circleci. It was due to lack of storage space. Freeing some memory and retrying fixed it.

Comment: Faced this issue recently while running tests on an emulator, I saved myself some time by connecting my phone to my computer instead. I was able to run the test on a physical device.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same problem after installing android studio on a new computer, and running instrumented tests on a connected device which I used previously to run my tests:

```
> Task :sdk-android:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite. Please check logs for details.
```

Then try again running those tests by command line with --debug option give more details about the problem:

```
./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=<MY_PACKAGE>.UnitTestSuite --debug
```

logs:

```
Caused by: com.google.testing.platform.core.error.UtpException: ErrorName: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE
….
2023-02-14T16:32:41.454+0100 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite. Please check logs for details.
2023-02-14T16:32:41.455+0100 [QUIET] [org.gradle.api.Task]
```

So in my case, it was just a problem of adb being unable to update test app. Just remove it from the device, then it worked for me!

Comment: Try to increase the emulator storage and retry this will sort out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your IDE? It looks like a bug to me

Comment: It was in circleci  CI/CD was working perfectly in android studio

Answer (score 0):

For us, the CI server had plenty of space remaining but we still encountered the `Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite.` error. I found that using the `-wipe-data` option when launching the emulator on our server resolved the issue. As per the documentation, using the `-wipe-data` option removed the app state that had been preserved across restarts and freed up the memory needed to run the tests.

> The virtual device preserves the app and its state data across restarts, in a user-data disk partition (userdata-qemu.img). To clear this data, start the emulator with the -wipe-data option or wipe the data in the AVD Manager, for example. For more information about the user-data partition and other storage, see the following section.

The full example command is: `emulator @AVD_NAME -wipe-data`.

Comment: As you specified plenty of space available extend emulator storage space then you will not face this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be two things. The first is to verify if the Android dependencies are correctly implemented (there is a difference between androidTestImplementation and testImplementation) and also the folders. In Android, there are two folders, androidTest and test. I think you should choose test.